# Facing this issue when i add flutter_sound package in my flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':flutter_sound:parseDebugLocalResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_sound:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: /Users/macbookpro/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/android.jar.
> > /Users/macbookpro/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/android.jar

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

i want to add flutter_sound packae. but it gives the above error